# ping localhost sometimes fails with sendmsg: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have a problem with network adapter (I think), look I trying to ping my self and got a error sometimes, how this can be? First time in my life I see this.

```
# ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=32 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=39 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=41 ttl=64 time=0.023 ms
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=43 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=47 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
213 packets transmitted, 118 received, 44% packet loss, time 212114ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.017/0.021/0.029/0.005 ms
You have mail in /var/mail/root
```

I have no iptables rules, server worked fine last months

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

if I have a luck and a connection established by ssh with server, this connection will be live and working fine, but after some minutes server stops accepting new connections and stops sending data to new ips. In/out data stops for few minutes.

I can't ping anything or connect to anywhere, but currently established connections works fine.

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
loopback        *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
default         99.99.99.99     0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 eth0
```

(99 my gw hidden sorry)

Any ideas what's happening?

Possible onboard lan is dying?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback interface -- which isn't your network adapter, but an in-kernel interface.  Getting intermittent `ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted` on the loopback interface sounds to me like something is either changing that interface or modifying the firewall.  It shouldn't randomly reject pings.

Comment: thanks problem almost solved, i got DDoS or DoS , nf_conntrack got full

Comment: A broken on-board NIC wouldn't cause the loopback interface to break: loopback data doesn't pass through the on-board NIC or its kernel driver. Kernel buffer depletion is one of the few ways the two interfaces can affect each other to so profound a degree.

Comment: Instead of posting that as a comment, you should add it as an answer and accept it, @waza123.